# Does Python '.join' keeps the input data order?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to convert a list into a string using `join()`. I have to keep the order of the list elements in the string. Can I be sure that Python never changes the order during conversion?

I use Python 2.7.x

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`str.join()` joins the elements of the iterable *in the order of iteration*, so it depends on the thing you are joining.

A *list* object is an *ordered* sequence, so yes, the order is preserved.